# Optimal Stopping Theory: Secretary problem with recall, known n, 100% chance of solicting success.

Tags: probability, optimization

I'm trying to find an optimal item in a list. Evaluating these items is very time-consuming, and I want to go fast. I know how many items there are, and I can choose one at any time.

Given some threshold d in (0, 1], how can I calculate how many items I have to evaluate such that the best item already evaluated is the best with probability > d?

Can this bound be changed if I use a very fast heuristic to order items from "probably good" to "probably not good"?

A paper or book discussing this in detail would be great.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming candidates arrive in a random order then $\lceil dn \rceil$, i.e. rounding up $dn$, seems an obvious answer since the probability the best is in the first $\lceil dn \rceil$ is $$\dfrac{\lceil dn \rceil}{n} \ge d$$

with equality if $dn$ is an integer. If you want strict inequality then $\lfloor dn \rfloor +1$

Comment: Well, don't I feel silly now. The thought even briefly flared up as I typed the question, but after close to an hour of searching, I guess my brain refused this simple answer and convinced itself, there would be a more complicated stochastical method behind it. Of course, you are right. Thanks.